# Running react with webpack dev server, using babel as loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

My index.js keeps getting the parse exception on the first simple HTML element.

I have tried to follow a lot of posts and tried to change between different way of configuration but I keep getting this error. I tried using babel as loader or babel-loader but still no use. 
My node module has the required dependencies so nothing seems to be missing. What I am doing wrong here, can anyone point out.

**Error**

```
ERROR in ./app/index.js Module parse failed: /mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/app/index.js Unexpected token (8:3) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:3)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1861:32)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1796:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/mnt/c/development_box/react_sandbox/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21) @ multi main
```

here are my files and configurations

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_sandbox",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "~1.14.0",
    "babel-core": "~6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.16.0",
    "react": "~15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "~15.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.16.2"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path')

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/build')
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname + '/app')

var config = 
{
    entry : APP_DIR + '/index.js',
    output : 
    {
        path : BUILD_DIR,
        filename : 'bundle.js',
        publicPath : '/'
    },
    devtool : 'source-map',
    devServer : 
    {
        inline : 'true',
        contentBase : BUILD_DIR,
        port : 3333
    },
    module :
    {
        loader : 
        [
        {
            test : /\.js?/,
            include : APP_DIR,
            loader : 'babel',
            query : 
            {
                presets : [ 'es2015', 'react' ] 
            }   

        }
        ]

    }
}

module.exports = config
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**command**

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: I suspect your webpack.config.js is not correctly configured. It should be `module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }]`

Comment: thanks a lot, the issue was just a 's' in my webpack.config.js

Comment: I wrote loader instead of loaders.

phew !!! this had me stuck for two days, should copy paste more than to type it all myself :)

Comment: No problems, I will ask to close this issue since it's a typographical error :)